# How do I see the non pretty version of a structure in vscode using gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

It's great that I can see a pretty version of a `vector`, which shows the intention rather than the implementation.  However, it would be good if I could see the underlying implementation too, esp since I can't use `operator[]` or `begin()` as, I assume, they are removed from the compilation, or maybe VSCode/gdb isn't able to send messages to objects? In any case, the result is the same.  In Visual Studio, I could drag an element and get the underlying access to the item, but since VSCode is getting the information 2nd hand from gdb, I'm assuming that is why it can't do that.

So, is there any way to get the non-pretty version of a object?  Also, how do I make pretty versions of my own objects?

## EDIT

This is what I'm getting when I attempt to print out a `std::vector`.

```
p A
$1 = std::vector of length 14, capacity 14 = {14310, 7617, 18936, 17452, 20601, 5250, 16520, 31557, 22799, 30304, 6225, 11009, 5845, 32610}
```

Apparently, I've found the gdb command to [disable a pretty printer](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Type-Printing-API.html#Type-Printing-API).  However, it doesn't seem to work.  The command I've tried are:

```
disable pretty-printer std::vector
disable pretty-printer "std::vector"
```

Comment: I'm very curious (and not a VScode/VS user): what is a "pretty version" of a std::vector? This is quite unclear to me.

Comment: @kebs, I've added an example of what I'm getting.  Iterators only display what they are pointing to.

Comment: In GDB, you could use `p/r` (print raw) command to examine the `vector` without invoking pretty-printer. No idea how to make VSCode do that.

Comment: Ah, good.  That's what I was looking for.  Couldn't find it.  Add it as an answer. Thx.

Comment: `disable type-printer` disables the type-printer, but you want to [disable pretty-printer](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty_002dPrinter-Commands.html).

Comment: @ssbssa Oops.  Fixed. How about disabling just one of them?  `-exec disable pretty-printer std::vector` still doesn't work.

Comment: Does `disable pretty-printer global .*;std::vector` work?

Comment: @ssbssa, yes. Ok I see what `global` is for, but why is `.*;` needed? And why doesn't it work without the `;`?  Also, now how do I disable it for a `vector::iterator`?  I can't just append `::iterator` to the command you provided.

Comment: Check `help disable pretty-printer` and `info pretty-printer` for details.

Comment: @ssbssa, yeah, I've done that already. The help is useless, and `info` doesn't explain the regex you prepended.

Comment: Actually, it does, because I've written that command according to this help.

Comment: @ssbssa, I don't see anywhere where it says to use `.*;` in front of the name.  So instead of writing comments, why not answer the question.  And it would help to quote the actual lines you are referring to.

Comment: `NAME-REGEXP matches the name of the pretty-printer. Individual printers in a collection are named as printer-name;subprinter-name.`

Comment: @ssbssa, ugh, subprinters.  Missed that.  Thx.